# Record Screen Specific View using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, service, ffmpeg, mediarecorder, screen-recording

I want to record my screen video in specific `View` link only want to record the action performing inside `LinearLayout`. Right now, `MediaRecorder` is recording whole screen, how to record specific part of screen?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaRecorder`, with the media projection APIs, records the whole screen. There is no option to record a specific part of the screen, at least as of Android 8.1. You would need to edit the full-screen video to crop it to only show the portion of the screen that matters to you.

Comment: Thanks for commit.
kindly let me know if there any other or alternate option except MediaRecorder. because i have search a lot, but did not get optimal result.

Comment: Only inside application
want to capture activities inside application, MainActivity->LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to capture the screenshot of the application of specific view.

```
public Bitmap takeScreenShot(View view) {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_LOW);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        if(view.getDrawingCache() == null) return null; 
        Bitmap snapshot = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        return snapshot;
    }
```

and if you want to record view you can use javacv library here is code example.

```
FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder("record.mp4",256,256);
try {
    recorder.setVideoCodec(avcodec.AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG4);
    recorder.setFormat("mp4");
    recorder.setFrameRate(30);
    recorder.setPixelFormat(avutil.PIX_FMT_YUV420P10);
    recorder.setVideoBitrate(1200);
    recorder.startUnsafe();
    for (int i=0;i< 5;i++)
    {
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
        recorder.record(bitmap);
    }
    recorder.stop();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: recorder.record(bitmap);
it Required Frame.