# Generating GIF from FrameLayout

Tags: android, gif, mp4, animated-gif, android-framelayout

Hi I'm trying to generate gif from animated view

In brief, I've ImageView and animated view inside FrameLayout, now i want to generate gif of main FrameLayout, minimum sdk level 19. getDrawingCache bitmap and arrange them in sequence to gif may cause memory out of bound issue.

[image]

when i click "start rec" i want gif or video of that particular view.

Comment: Could you please share your code as of now so that I can understand it better and answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: hey @AkshatTiwari please check image attached

Comment: Hey @CristianHoldunu please check now

Comment: If I understand your requirements correctly, the answer to this is probably out of scope of a SO question. You'll need a bitmap processing pipeline that can transform the bitmaps into gifs, with your implementation supplying the bitmaps at the rate you desire.

Possibly this? https://github.com/nbadal/android-gif-encoder

Comment: like @LukeDuncan said, you need to build a pipeline to encode the images into a gif. I think for your usecase, you can use the parent `ViewGroup` to extract the bitmaps using `getDrawingCache` method at different intervals, then feed the bitmaps into a GIF assembly pipeline.

Comment: @CristianHoldunu i already tried that but it's too slow and cause memory out of bound issue, and cause gif lagging

Comment: That could be optimised and you don't need to store all the images in memory. If you want a true screen recording, you can try MediaProjection https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/av-capture

Comment: Please check these questions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336338/screen-video-record-of-current-activity-android,    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48401817/record-screen-specific-view-using-mediarecorder

Comment: @MahendraGohil, did you find any solution if no, let me know I can help, I've already made the same thing in one of my apps

Comment: hello @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI still not found any solution

Comment: @MahendraGohil, I've given my answer, please follow all steps, and you will get what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to implement these libraries :

```
implementation 'com.blankj:utilcodex:1.30.6'
implementation 'com.waynejo:androidndkgif:0.3.3'
implementation 'com.jiang.android.observablescheduler:schedule:1.0.1'
```

1. The first one is a useful library, which contains all the necessary
   classes to help you, such as (`ImageUtils`, `PathUtils`...).
2. The second one is for the encoding and decoding **GIF**.
3. The Third one is for replacing the `AsyncTask` class with
   `java.util.concurrent`

---

**The XML :** I tried to make the same thing you did :

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewToBeRecorded"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="View To Be Recorded"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/changeBg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Change Background"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/startRecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start Record"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/stopRecord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="Stop Record"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

**Java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private Button changeBg, startRecord, stopRecord;
    private RelativeLayout viewToBeRecorded;
    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private GifEncoder mGifEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeViews();

        startRecord.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            isRecording = true;
            ToastUtils.showShort("Start recording...");
            startRecord.setEnabled(false);
            stopRecord.setEnabled(true);
            generateGIF();
        });

        stopRecord.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            isRecording = false;
            ToastUtils.showShort("Stop recording...");
            startRecord.setEnabled(true);
            stopRecord.setEnabled(false);
        });

        changeBg.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
            viewToBeRecorded.setBackgroundColor(color);
        });

    }

    private void generateGIF() {
        JObservable.create((JObservable.OnSubscribe<String>) mSubscriber -> {
            try {
                File storageDir = new File(PathUtils.getExternalPicturesPath() + "/GIFs");
                FileUtils.createOrExistsDir(storageDir);
                File gifFile = new File(storageDir, "GIF" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".gif");
                String outputPath = gifFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap firstFrame = ImageUtils.view2Bitmap(viewToBeRecorded);
                try {
                    mGifEncoder.init(firstFrame.getWidth(), firstFrame.getHeight(), outputPath, GifEncoder.EncodingType.ENCODING_TYPE_SIMPLE_FAST);
                    while (isRecording) {
                        Bitmap frame = ImageUtils.view2Bitmap(viewToBeRecorded);
                        mGifEncoder.encodeFrame(frame, 100);
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                    mGifEncoder.close();
                    mSubscriber.notifyData(outputPath);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mSubscriber.error(e);
            }
        }).workedOn(Schedules.background())
                .subscribeOn(Schedules.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void notifyData(String outputPath) {
                        FileUtils.notifySystemToScan(outputPath);
                        ToastUtils.showShort("GIF saved!");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void error(Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("View2GIF", "generateGIF throw error : " + t.getMessage());
                    }
                });

    }

    private void initializeViews() {
        viewToBeRecorded = findViewById(R.id.viewToBeRecorded);
        changeBg = findViewById(R.id.changeBg);
        stopRecord = findViewById(R.id.stopRecord);
        startRecord = findViewById(R.id.startRecord);
        mGifEncoder = new GifEncoder();
    }
```

**OUTPUT :**

[image]

Don't forget to add :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and make sure the Storage permission is **granted**

Comment: Hello @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI i appreciate your effort, but this not helps me. i cause gif lagging issue bcause while capturing bitmap of view number of frame skiped between two bitmap

Comment: @MahendraGohil you can change the value of sleep, for example `Thread.sleep(20);` this will make your app capture a frame every **20ms**

Comment: Hello @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI i already tried that

Comment: @MahendraGohil you didn't add your animation code in your question, add it so I can test it with my code

Comment: Sorry @Mouaad Abdelghafour AITALI but i already told in question that genrating bitmap sequence won't work for me

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no other way to do that, Android OS does not provide any way to record a specific view, however, try this : https://github.com/z4hyoung/ViewRecorder

Comment: Did exactly what you have mentioned above. JObservable, Schedules, notifyData and error are showing in red at MainActivity.java.. I tried to see if there is import class and there isn't one for this..